# Finding a connected subset of edges with minimal sum of weights for a distributed network

Tags: graphs, distributed-systems

Let there be $n$ processes in a general connected network with no leader such that each process has a distinct UID.

Each edge has a weight , with weights being positive or negative.

Assume that each process knows $D$, the diameter of the network.

I need to find a subset of edges such that the subgraph formed by them is a connected graph and the sum of the weights is minimal, among all possible connected subgraphs in $O(n)$ rounds.

My attempt:

First we can find a leader to the network by applying the Flooding algorithm which takes $O(n)$ rounds, given that each process knows D.
After we have a leader, we can ask it to perform Kruskal algorithm on $2^n$ induced subgraphs to find $2^n$ MSTs, after which we can extend if we see any negative edges we did not use along the way.

This does achieve $O(n)$ rounds due to the leader selection algorithm  but the computation time is long, is there any way to improve upon it?